# the division $14^{256}$ by $17$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

> What the rest of the division $14^{256}$ by $17$?

$$14^2\equiv9\pmod{17}\\14^4\equiv13\pmod{17}\\14^8\equiv16\equiv-1\pmod{17}\\(14^8)^{32}\equiv(-1)^{32}\equiv1\pmod{17}$$The rest is $1$, correct?